# Array keeps being populated with wrong index

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

So i'm trying to see if any of the user is an admin in any event. For some reason, the array will be filled with the index of the last find. Any idea why this is happening?

```
for(var x = 0;x<=10;x++){
            console.log(x);
            var current = x; 
            firebase.database().ref('/Event/' + x + "/admins").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.val()); 
              if(snapshot.val()==uid){
                console.log("Match found at "+(current)+"!");
                matchingEvents.push(current);
              }
            });    
}
```

The array ends up looking like this:
[10,10,10,10,10]

Comment: What is `x` and what does it say when you log it?

Comment: And what does the snapshot.val() gives you.

Comment: You should either use `let` or wrap your innards in an IIFE that you can pass the index into, otherwise X will always be 10, since your DB stuff is async.

Comment: x will increment in the log @Mikey . snapshot.val() gives me the uid of the admins baradwaj

Answer (score 0):

The loop is already finished by the time the anonymous function is called and so `current = 10`. It's a scope issue relating to closures.

A correct way of doing this might be

```
.then((function(current) {
    return function(snapshot) {
        // Things using current
    }
})(current));
```

Comment: How is it though? The function is within the loop

Comment: The call to the `.then` method is inside your loop, but it merely passes the anonymous function as an argument in each iteration. The references to `current` inside those anonymous functions all end up pointing to the same variable, which is the last time current is updated at the end of the loop, so it ends up with value 10.

Comment: Look up closures if you want more information on this :)